# Access row index of 2-D array from row pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 2D array as follows:

```
struct tab **table;
table = new tab*[n+1];  
for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
    table[i] = new tab[n+1];
```

Now I have a pointer to the some row of the 2-D array as `tab* start = table[10]`. My doubt is that say, I call a function and pass start as an argument. Then how can I get the row index (i.e. 10 in this case) of the table using start ?

Comment: I guess the only way of knowing the row then is by iterating the 2D array and checking if the row pointer equals the one passed.

Comment: Why not make a class for this anyway? to simplify lookup?

Comment: @Nandini Singhal  You can not. An element of an array does not have information about its position in the array. You should pass the index separatly to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because you are using dynamic memory allocation; meaning the elements will not be stored in a continuous memory location.

But maybe that is not what you want....notice that table[10] and &table[10] are different things.

Since you are using  pointer to pointer you can use offsets to get the index of any &tab[index] element. They are the columns  in your 2D array, allocated by `table = new tab*[n+1]`, stored in an continuous memory location. Each of these locations holds a tab*, so rows of your matrix.